# Sending JSON in POST request with retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, post, retrofit

I've seen this questions many times and tried many solutions but without resolving my problem, I'm trying to send a json in a POST request using retrofit, I'm not an expert in programming so I may miss something obvious.

My JSON is in a string and looks like that:

```
{"id":1,"nom":"Hydrogène","slug":"hydrogene"}
```

My Interface (called **APIService.java**) looks like that:

```
@POST("{TableName}/{ID}/update/0.0")
Call<String> cl_updateData(@Path("TableName") String TableName, @Path("ID") String ID);
```

And my **ClientServiceGenerator.java** looks like that:

```
public class ClientServiceGenerator{
private static OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String URL) {
    Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient).build();
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}}
```

And finally here is the code in my activity

```
APIService client = ClientServiceGenerator.createService(APIService.class, "http://mysiteexample.com/api.php/");
    Call<String> call = client.cl_updateData("atomes", "1");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<String> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            if (response.code() == 200 && response.body() != null){
                Log.e("sd", "OK");
            }else{
                Log.e("Err", response.message()+" : "+response.raw().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            AlertDialog alertError = QuickToolsBox.simpleAlert(EditDataActivity.this, "updateFail", t.getMessage(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            alertError.show();
        }
    });
```

Tell me if you need anything else, hope someone could help me.

**EDIT**
Didn't mention it first time but my JSON won't always be with the same keys (id, nom, slug).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you need to create an object to represent the json you need:

```
public class Data {
    int id;
    String nom;
    String slug;

    public Data(int id, String nom, String slug) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.slug = slug;
    }
}
```

Then, modify your service to be able to send this object:

```
@POST("{TableName}/{ID}/update/0.0")
Call<String> cl_updateData(@Path("TableName") String TableName, @Path("ID") String ID, @Body Data data);
```

Finally, pass this object:

```
Call<String> call = client.cl_updateData("atomes", "1", new Data(1, "Hydrogène", "hydrogene"));
```

**UPD**

To be able to send any data use `Object` instead of `Data`:

```
@POST("{TableName}/{ID}/update/0.0")
Call<String> cl_updateData(@Path("TableName") String TableName, @Path("ID") String ID, 
        @Body Object data);
```

Comment: What if I wanted to use the same method for multiple request, without using the same types ? I mean, I can't use a class like Data cause I don't know how my datas will be, it was an example so I won't always use id, nom and slug. Is there a was to do that by using a List or something ?

Comment: @Teasel that's not a problem. Just use `Object` instead of `Data` and pass whatever data you need

Comment: Sorry to bother you Sir but may I have a little example ? My brain is kinda burning right now, how do I use an Object for this ?

Comment: @Teasel updated my answer

Comment: Still not working, maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Looks like my API isn't receiving any datas

Comment: Get any exceptions on the client?

Comment: Yep, Error 404, it's normal cause my API is sending a 404 error when there is no result.
I use this API: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/

Comment: I don't know man, see the server logs. retrofit service looks ok

Comment: I'll see, thanks anyway ! I think your answer could solve most problems so I'll mark it as the good one.

Comment: you are not allowed to vote until 15 points, but you can accept my answer so I can earn my 15 points)

Comment: Hey mate, just wanted to tell you that I succeeded, thank you very much for your help !

Comment: @Teasel glad I helped!)

Comment: @Teasel Can you please let me know How did you pass different values or Body object for different requests?

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you very much!